# New service account tokens are not signed

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I create a new service account token in Kubernetes, it is not signed. I am using the command

`kubectl create -f default-token-create.yaml`

The yaml is the following

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
     name: default-token-abcd  
     namespace: staging
     annotations:
       kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
       kubernetes.io/service-account.namespace: staging
    type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

I also verified that the ca cert for kubernetes is associated with the api-server. This was previously working and now is not.

What am I missing?

I have tried creating a new service account and having kubernetes create the token as well as using the above script to manually create one. Neither works.

This is the create-token yaml:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
     name: default-token-abcd  
     namespace: staging
     annotations:
       kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
       kubernetes.io/service-account.namespace: staging
    type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Expected results: A token created that is a proper jwt with the jwt header as well as the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `.yaml` file you provided a ServiceAccount with name `default` should exist.

I suggest that you create a ServiceAccount via `kubectl` or `yaml` file, a token should be generated automatically. It will be placed in `Secret` resource, which you can later fetch via `kubectl`.

Comment: Hi Danil,  I also had tried using `kubectl` to create a new service account. The token that was created was also not signed. So both manually creating a token or creating a service account created the same issue.

Comment: This was solved. Ended up having to remove the namespace that was creating bad tokens and then re-adding it. Not sure why it broke in the first place.